# json.loads(jsonstring) in Python fails if string has a "\r" i.e. carriage return character

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am getting a JSON string which has a `"\r"` character somewhere e.g. `"{"data":"foo \r\n bar"}"` when I try to parse it throws `ValueError`.

```
>>> j="""{"data":"foo \r\n bar"}"""
>>> import json
>>> f=json.loads(j)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    f=json.loads(j)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 13 (char 13)
>>> j[13]
'\r'
```

`"\r"` is a perfectly legal character in a Python string.

**How can I parse this JSON string, such that**

```
>>> dct = somehow_parse_json(j)
>>> dct['data']
'foo \r\n bar'
```

I could easily just find and pop carriage return characters, but I would prefer if they can be saved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should escape slashes in JSON:

```
j="""{"data":"foo \\r\\n bar"}"""
```

If you are not escaping them, your JSON is invalid (being valid Python string).

Comment: Raw strings would make it easier to read, additionally: `j = r"""{"data":"foo \r\n bar"}"""`

Comment: @DrTyrsa - I am not creating the json, so i would have to "seek and escape"

Comment: @Thanatos - r"""{"data":"foo \\r\\n bar"}""" solved the issue, thanks, you should have posted it as an answer :)

Comment: @Optimus How has it solved it? `r"""{"data":"foo \r\n bar"}""" ` is exactly the same that `"""{"data":"foo \\r\\n bar"}"""`.

Comment: @Optimus: The `r"""..."""` string only had a single slash before the `r`, i.e., `\r\n`. See my comment again. The `r"""..."""` string I posted is simply a different way of writing what DrTyrsa posted, the only difference between the two is for the human reader.

Comment: @DrTyrsa - yes,  r"""{"data":"foo \r\n bar"}""" is exactly the same as """{"data":"foo \\r\\n bar"}""", both work, but i don't have to add additional slashes when using this r"""{"data":"foo \r\n bar"}""", thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Logically `python` is doing what should have been done !

Its the same old `CRLF` (inspired from typewriters)
CR = Carraige Return
LF = Line Feed

'\r' stands for `CR`
But '\n' = CR + LF
so, my point is that for `json` its definitely not valid.

For Eg:
    print '\n 123456\rone'
    # one3456

Now, how to use `\r` anyway ?

```
# if j is your json
j = j.replace('\r','\\r')
```

That should only escape `\r` with `\\r`

Comment: json is coming from facebook graph api, If it is not valid json, i will still have to parse it, thanks for help anyways