# Is there any way to have pycorenlp's `nlp.annotate()` always return the same type of result?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to run [pycorenlp](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp) to tokenize a text containing non-ASCII characters. Sometimes `nlp.annotate()` returns a dictionary, and sometimes it returns a string.

For example,

```
'''
From https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp/blob/master/example.py
'''
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import pprint
import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
    text = u"tab with good effect, denies pain".encode('utf-8')
    print('type(text): {0}'.format(type(text)))

    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
        'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit',
        'outputFormat': 'json'
    })
    #pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    #pp.pprint(output)
    print('type(output): {0}'.format(type(output)))

    text = u"tab with good effect\u0013\u0013, denies pain".encode('utf-8')
    print('\ntype(text): {0}'.format(type(text)))
    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
        'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit',
        'outputFormat': 'json'
    })
    print('type(output): {0}'.format(type(output)))
```

outputs:

```
type(text): <type 'str'>
type(output): <type 'dict'>

type(text): <type 'str'>
type(output): <type 'unicode'>
```

I notice that when `type(output)` is `<type 'unicode'>`, I get this warning in Stanford CoreNLP server:

```
WARNING: Untokenizable: ‼ (U+13, decimal: 19)
```

Is there any way to have `nlp.annotate()` always return the same type of result?

---

The [Stanford CoreNLP server](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) was launched using:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer 9000
```

I use Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0, pycorenlp 0.3.0 and python 3.5 x64 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix:

```
import json
# to place right after `output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={…})`
if type(output) is str or type(output) is unicode:
    output = json.loads(output, strict=False)
```

I used `strict=False` because of [Python json.loads fails with `ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 33 (char 33)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16544933/395857).