# Extra data JSON decoding error from api response

Tags: python, json, api, encode

```
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 9 - line 1 column 36 (char 8 - 35)
```

Here's the data I tried using json(). It is an api response. But it shows the above error. Is it because it is a dictionary with nested lists? Any ideas how I can go about solving this?

```
{"AAPL":{"chart":[{"close":133.7,"high":134.32,"low":133.23,"open":133.77,"symbol":"AAPL","volume":60214200,"id":"HISTORICAL_PRICES","key":"AAPL","subkey":"","date":"2021-06-23","updated":162449640
1000,"changeOverTime":0,"marketChangeOverTime":0,"uOpen":133.77,"uClose":133.7,"uHigh":134
.32,"uLow":133.23,"uVolume":60214200,"fOpen":133.77,"fClose":133.7,"fHigh":134.32,"fLow":1
33.23,"fVolume":60214200,"label":"Jun 23, 21","change":0,"changePercent":0},
{"close":133.41,"high":134.64,"low":132.93,"open":134.45,"symbol":"AAPL","volume":68710998
,"id":"HISTORICAL_PRICES","key":"AAPL","subkey":"","date":"2021-06-24","updated":162458376
6000,"changeOverTime":-0.0021690351533282877,"marketChangeOverTime":-
0.0021690351533282877,"uOpen":134.45,"uClose":133.41,"uHigh":134.64,"uLow":132.93,"uVolume
":68710998,"fOpen":134.45,"fClose":133.41,"fHigh":134.64,"fLow":132.93,"fVolume":68710998,
"label":"Jun 24, 21","change":-0.28999999999999204,"changePercent":-0.0022},
{"close":133.11,"high":133.89,"low":132.81,"open":133.46,"symbol":"AAPL","volume":70783746
,"id":"HISTORICAL_PRICES","key":"AAPL","subkey":"","date":"2021-06-25","updated":162467027
8000,"changeOverTime":-0.004412864622288519,"marketChangeOverTime":-
0.004412864622288519,"uOpen":133.46,"uClose":133.11,"uHigh":133.89,"uLow":132.81,"uVolume"
:70783746,"fOpen":133.46,"fClose":133.11,"fHigh":133.89,"fLow":132.81,"fVolume":70783746,"
label":"Jun 25, 21","change":-0.29999999999998295,"changePercent":-0.0022}]},"GOOG":
{"chart":
[{"close":2529.23,"high":2555.92,"low":2525.04,"open":2531,"symbol":"GOOG","volume":984658
,"id":"HISTORICAL_PRICES","key":"GOOG","subkey":"","date":"2021-06-23","updated":162449642
6000,"changeOverTime":0,"marketChangeOverTime":0,"uOpen":2531,"uClose":2529.23,"uHigh":255
5.92,"uLow":2525.04,"uVolume":984658,"fOpen":2531,"fClose":2529.23,"fHigh":2555.92,"fLow":
2525.04,"fVolume":984658,"label":"Jun 23, 21","change":0,"changePercent":0},
{"close":2545.64,"high":2550.71,"low":2539.2,"open":2541.07,"symbol":"GOOG","volume":94666
2,"id":"HISTORICAL_PRICES","key":"GOOG","subkey":"","date":"2021-06-24","updated":16245837
77000,"changeOverTime":0.006488140659410118,"marketChangeOverTime":0.006488140659410118,"u
Open":2541.07,"uClose":2545.64,"uHigh":2550.71,"uLow":2539.2,"uVolume":946662,"fOpen":2541
.07,"fClose":2545.64,"fHigh":2550.71,"fLow":2539.2,"fVolume":946662,"label":"Jun 24, 
21","change":16.409999999999854,"changePercent":0.0065},
{"close":2539.9,"high":2550.1,"low":2528.88,"open":2539.14,"symbol":"GOOG","volume":167429
7,"id":"HISTORICAL_PRICES","key":"GOOG","subkey":"","date":"2021-06-25","updated":16246702
19000,"changeOverTime":0.004218675248988851,"marketChangeOverTime":0.004218675248988851,"u
Open":2539.14,"uClose":2539.9,"uHigh":2550.1,"uLow":2528.88,"uVolume":1674297,"fOpen":2539
.14,"fClose":2539.9,"fHigh":2550.1,"fLow":2528.88,"fVolume":1674297,"label":"Jun 25, 
21","change":-5.739999999999782,"changePercent":-0.0023}]}}
```

Comment: Please show the code you used to read this JSON. I don't know if it's copy-paste error, but pasting that *exact* block of text to a file does not seem to produce valid JSON, because there are unnecessary line breaks in between values. But after formatting it properly, using built-in `json.load` reads the JSON data just fine. Nested lists shouldn't be a problem. I suggest doing the same, copying that to a file and reading it directly with your simplejson code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python json.loads fails with \`ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 33 (char 33)\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295439/python-json-loads-fails-with-valueerror-invalid-control-character-at-line-1-c)