# How to parse input string in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I working on an AWS Lambda function in python, sample below, and hooked up to an API Gateway via lambda_proxy integration. I have a post method in my api, which posts a json object in the request body as such:

```
{'request' : 'here are the details'}
```

In the lambda function I read the payload as such. This works but when there is a newline character in the request string, I get a `json decode error`. How to fix this?

```
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):

   #read body
   body = json.loads(event['body'])
   #print body
   ...
```

i did the json.dumps(event) , output below

```
{
   "resource": "/myresource",
   "path": "/myresource",
   "httpMethod": "POST",
   "headers": {
      ...
    }, 
    ...
    "body": "{\"request\": \"here are the details \nhere some other details\"}",
"isBase64Encoded": false
 }
....
}
```

Comment: What is the full error message? What exactly is `event`?

Comment: @kyagu if the json object you put it the question is the result of `json.dumps(event)` then you should probably do `json.loads(event)` instead of `event['body']`.

Comment: @MoGanji - thanks , i just updated the question with json.dumps(event)

Comment: Why do you put `\n` into the request in the first place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python json.loads fails with \`ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 33 (char 33)\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295439/python-json-loads-fails-with-valueerror-invalid-control-character-at-line-1-c)